# how to check if api variables are updated in js

Tags: javascript, json

I have made an covid website app using rapidapi covid API, so now I'm struggling. I have no idea how to code that if covid statistic is not updated not to change date, feedback appreciated. Here is my code:

```
  const settings = {
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=GEORGIA",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-key": "bc0019aac3msh86f039dbf1157b6p1b7843jsn2aaad402201d",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {


  console.log(response);
  $("#date").text(response.response[0].day);
  $("#infected").text(
    Number(response.response[0].cases.new)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
  $("#death").text(
    Number(response.response[0].deaths.new)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
  $("#tests").text(
    Number(response.response[0].tests.total)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
  $("#country").text(response.parameters.country);
  $("#recovered").text(
    Number(response.response[0].cases.recovered)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
  $("#active").text(
    Number(response.response[0].cases.active)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
  $("#totald").text(
    Number(response.response[0].deaths.total)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  );
});

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you update each of the values, check if it's different from the previous time. Then only update the date if one of the values has changed.

```
function get_number(str) {
  return str.toString()
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  let changed = false;
  let cur = response.response[0];
  let new_infected = get_number(cur.cases.new);
  if (new_infected != $("#infected").text()) {
    changed = true;
    $("#infected").text(new_infected);
  }
  let new_deaths = get_number(cur.deaths.new);
  if (new_deaths != $("#death").text()) {
    $("death").text(new_deaths);
    changed = true;
  }
  let new_tests = get_number(cur.tests.total);
  if (new_tests != $("#tests").text()) {
    $("tests").text(new_tests);
    changed = true;
  }
  let new_country = response.parameters.country;
  if (new_country != $("#country").text()) {
    $("#country").text(new_country);
    changed = true;
  }
  let new_recovered = get_number(cur.cases.recovered);
  if (new_recovered != $("#recovered").text()) {
    $("#recovered").text(new_recovered);
    changed = true;
  }
  let new_active = get_number(cur.cases.active);
  if (new_active != $("#active").text()) {
    $("#active").text(new_active);
    changed = true;
  }
  let new_totald = get_number(cur.deaths.total);
  if (new_totald != $("#totald").text()) {
    $("#totald").text(new_totald);
    changed = true;
  }
  if (changed) {
    $("#date").text(response.response[0].day);
  }
});
```